# Having trouble replicating css border and box-shadow values in react-native Stylesheet

Tags: css, react-native

[This is the target spec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOo1z.jpg)

[And this is where I am currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vP8Co.jpg)

This is the CSS code of the spec

```
.card-bg {
    height: 410px;
    width: 343px;
    border: 1px solid #33CC99;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
}
```

And this is the card container from the stylesheet

```
  container: {
    width: '100%',
    padding: 24,
    borderRadius: 8,
    borderColor: '#33CC99',
    borderWidth: 1,
    shadowColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.16)",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 10,
      height: 10,
    },
    shadowRadius: 2.22,
    elevation: 3,
  },
```

The main problem is that the borders always seem to appear on the outside of the shadows when I add elevation. Also I haven't been able to replicate the depth of the shadows. I tried to implement it with styled components but that crashed the app for whatever reason. Hope someone can help I've been stuck on this for a couple of days now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `box-shadow: 0 0 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16)` 
represents

> box-shadow: [horizontal offset] [vertical offset] [blur radius]
>   [optional spread radius] [color];

so, what you'll have to do is :

```
container: {
    backgroundColor:'white',
    padding: 24,
    margin:15,
    borderRadius: 8,
    borderColor: '#33CC99',
    borderWidth: 1,
    ...Platform.select({
     ios: {
       shadowColor: '#000',
       shadowRadius: 2,
       shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
       shadowOpacity: 0.16,
     },
     android: {
       elevation: 4,
     },
    })
  },
```

but you can always alter the shadowRadius and height to match the target spec

Answer (score -1):

Best Way to apply shadow in react native

- elevation not working in ios so you use shadow props
- You can create a shadow from below link

https://ethercreative.github.io/react-native-shadow-generator/

ex :

```
card:{

shadowColor: "#000",

shadowOffset: {
    width: 0,
    height: 2,
},

shadowOpacity: 0.25,

shadowRadius: 3.84,

elevation: 5,

}
```

[image]